# Parsing JSON from webserver in Haskell

Tags: json, haskell

Let's say I want to parse the JSON from http://reddit.com/r/haskell.json

```
main = do
  rsp <- simpleHTTP (getRequest "http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell.json")
  str <- fmap (takeWhile isAscii) (getResponseBody rsp)
```

I now have a string ready to be parsed. However, Aeson's `decode` function has the following type signature:

```
decode :: FromJSON a => 
  bytestring-0.10.0.2:Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString -> Maybe a
```

How can I decode the JSON from that String? Or is there a better way to decode from a GET request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`simpleHTTP` is polymorphic. The contained response body can be any of strict `ByteString`, lazy `ByteString`, or `String`. It picks one of those to match the `Request ty` value passed to it. Unfortunately, `HTTP` is an old library and poorly maintained - it sort of minimally added the polymorphism necessary to work with those three types, but not everywhere it could have to make the library friendly to use. For instance, using `getRequest` forces the response to be a `String`, nullifying the polymorphism in `simpleHTTP`.

Here's a minimal working example of grabbing the contents of that URL with `HTTP` and decoding them with `aeson`.

```
import Network.URI
import Network.HTTP
import Data.Aeson

-- There's absolutely no reason that this function shouldn't be in HTTP.
-- It's just as unsafe and terrible as getRequest is. In fact, this is a
-- strictly more general type than getRequest has, so there's no reason
-- it shouldn't just replace it.
getRequest_ :: HStream ty => String -> Request ty
getRequest_ s = let Just u = parseURI s in defaultGETRequest_ u

main :: IO ()
main = do
    rsp <- simpleHTTP $ getRequest_ "http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell.json"
    body <- getResponseBody rsp
    print (decode $ body :: Maybe Value)
```

Note that it's the use of `decode` that finally pins down the polymorphic type of `simpleHTTP` there. It's just that in this version, it's not disagreeing with what `getRequest` says about the type in your code.

Comment: It is indeed `simpleHTTP` from the `HTTP` package. How can I tell it to use the proper `ByteString` so I can feed it to the `decode` function?

Comment: @Nick Just feed it to the `decode` function. That's all it takes to make sure it's the right type. That's the whole point of type inference.

Comment: After getting the `rsp`, I tried `sb <- getResponseBody rsp` and then `decode sb`, but that failed with a type error because it expected `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString` but instead got `[Char]`

Comment: Nick: Add your updated code (all of it) to the question and it'll be easier to help. Using `decode` with `getResponseBody` should just work, but maybe you are using `sb` somewhere else too which causes it to be incorrectly inferred as `String`.